# Getting JSON_PARSER_ERROR while calling Google FCM in MobileFirstAdapter JS

Tags: javascript, json, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mfp

I am calling Google FCM Api for Push Notificaation. This is my code in JS file:

```
    function sendNotificationToUser() {
      var request={
        path :'/fcm/send',
        method: 'POST',
        returnedContentType : 'text/plain',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': ' application/json',
          'Authorization': SERVER_KEY
        },
    parameters : {
            'to': USER_AUTH_KEY,
            'notification':JSON.stringify({
                  'title': 'Welcome',                
                  'body':'Hi there'
            })
        };
    var response = WL.Server.invokeHttp(request);
    return response;
```

But getting error saying BadRequest, JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected character (t) at position 0.

I am using MFP 7.1 and making the call to **https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send**

Someone please guide me.

Comment: Why are you doing this when MFP gives you unified API's to send push notifications?

Comment: I need to send Push Notification from my Backend service which will gets called from some other servers.

Comment: So which server actually talks to FCM?MFP server or your backend?

Comment: My Backend WAS Server.

Comment: In that case, you should not be calling FCM directly from MFP. You should invoke your WAS backend service in a HTTP adapter call, which will inturn call FCM. You should only be passing the required parameters in the MFP Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Since your backend service ( running on WAS) is contacting FCM to send the notification, you should not be invoking FCM directly from within MFP adapter.

Use a HTTP adapter to call the backend and pass the parameters to your backend service.

If you intend to call FCM directly from MFP adapter, you should server side Push APIs and not invoke FCM endpoint directly.

Refer to [WL.Server.notify*](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Server.html#notifyDevice) APIs